# Generate Data which is signed by a Private Key

Tags: cryptography, java, digital-signature

I have data which is signed by a Private Key. Now how do I obtain the initial data which was signed? I went through many examples using Bouncy Castle but they were mainly for verifying if some data is signed by the right Private Key.

```
CMSSignedData s = new CMSSignedData(new CMSProcessableByteArray(toverify.getBytes()),contents);
SignerInformationStore signers = s.getSignerInfos();
SignerInformation signerInfo = (SignerInformation)signers.getSigners().iterator().next();
boolean result = signerInfo.verify(new JcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder().setProvider("BC").build(cert.getPublicKey()));
```

The CMSSignedData object takes two parameters:-

1.toverify - This is the sample string which has been signed

2.contents - This is the signed data obtained

The problem is I have only the 'contents' with me. I have to generate the 'toverify' part to validate the signature.

How do I generate the 'toverify' string?

Comment: What you're asking is essentially the same as "how can I get the original data from the hash?". The signature is only designed to verify the contents (even your code indicates as much).

Comment: @deed02392 Not so sure; I'm no expert but... on the surface I would expect the "signed data" (contents) to have both the original and the signature.  If that assumption on my part is true, then this question is about how to parse the "signed data".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot recover the data from the signature. The signature is a small piece of data, it's always the same size for a given signature scheme, key and representation. If you have a signature and a public key, you can verify that the signature is was produced by the corresponding private key, but that information alone is rarely useful. Usually, the point of verifying a signature is to validate that some data is authentic. You need to have the data that you're validating!

Answer (score 0):

> I have to generate the 'toverify' part to validate the signature.

No you don't. You should already have it supplied along with the signature, and also the public key. Otherwise the entire process is pointless. A signature is meaningless without the data that it is signing. In any case you can't recover data from a signature. It's not an encryption.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one way to do this, and I'll explain how:

1. perform the raw modular exponentiation using the public exponent and the modulus (which make up the public key)
2. retrieve the hash value that was used as part of the signature data
3. now brute force the plain text by trying all possible values against the given hash

If brute force is too complex then you are out of luck. (One way) hashes are an integral part of signature schemes, and they have been *designed* to be irreversible as the name suggests.

There is - or better was - a standard for RSA that gives (partial) message recovery. That standard, ISO 9796 part 1 was however withdrawn because of security concerns. Nowadays it is better to use ECC signatures instead if you want a signature with low overhead.